# javascript loop for chart and php loop values

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I have a flot bar chart which has a FOR loop to create bars. I need to supply values to it using PHP while loop so it can provide real data. Here are the code samples I am using.

javascript for loop for bar chart (it works)

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i += 1)
data3.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
```

Now my php code is

```
$sql_table = "SELECT * FROM mytable ";
$sql_table_query = mysql_query($sql_table, $conn);
while ($sql_tbl_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_table_query)) {
echo $sql_tbl_rows['value'];
}
```

What I need is to move $sql_tbl_rows['value'] to the javascript loop where it says parseInt(Math.random() * 30)

However the javascript has its own loop and it won't accept php loop.

Please help.

Comment: If you want to pass data from PHP to JS, you can consider making an AJAX call to the PHP script. Also, you *really* shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: thanks. but i am newbie with javascript. so not sure how to do it through ajax.

Comment: If you are using jQuery already, you can use their `$.ajax()` method. (1) Make an AJAX request to PHP script; (2) PHP script performs query (you should use either MySQLi or PDO), and returns/echos data in JSON; (3) AJAX receives JSON data, and you use it for your chart. There are plenty of resources on StackOverflow that will help you with this, all you need is to put a little bit of effort in searching.

Comment: I wish someone could have given the right direction with the above examples. thank you for your suggestion anyway.